# Compositor Time Node Cap

Tags: compositing-nodes, eevee-render-engine

Trying to set the end of my Time node to a big number but blender won't let me stopping at 32,767. After some suspicious poking it turns out that is also 2^15-1. Is this a bug in Blender or a limitation in the language Blender was written in? Any workarounds in the meantime `<edit>like with a script or something<edit>`?

Specs:
Blender 2.80.74
2015 MacBook Pro (buy necessity not by choice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back and tidied this blend file up so you can basically hit render animation once in each workspace and get the result you want. Download it [here](https://30salt.gumroad.com/l/BlenderColorAnalysisTool).

I went through the tutorial you provided and came up with a workaround.

[image: Import your movie, delete the audio track and add the Speed Control effect strip. Set the end frame of your original strip to the resolution of your final image, in this case its 200.]
Import your movie, delete the audio track and add the Speed Control effect strip. Set the end frame of your original strip to the resolution of your final image, in this case its 200.

[image: Render the sequence. You will get 200 .png files]
Render the sequence. You will get 200 .png files

[image: In the compositing workspace, import the image files as image strip and set up the node group as instructed in the video you provided.]
In the compositing workspace, import the image files as image strip and set up the node group as instructed in the video you provided.

[image: Duplicate the node group and make a new copy of it. In the duplicated node group, change the offset to 1 and plug both node groups into an Alpha Over node. Control the Alpha Over Fac with the Translate node from the tutorial.]
Duplicate the node group and make a new copy of it. In the duplicated node group, change the offset to 1 and plug both node groups into an Alpha Over node. Control the Alpha Over Fac with the Translate node from the tutorial.

[image: Hit F12 to render a single image. Open the said image from an Image Sequence node and plug the image output to the first Image slot of the previous Alpha Over node.]
Hit F12 to render a single image. Open the said image from an Image Sequence node and plug the image output to the first Image slot of the previous Alpha Over node.

[image: Change the Current Frame to 2. You should see a preview of your second render in the Viewer node. As of right now, there is only one image in the Image node. Change it to an Image Sequence and set the Offset to -1. This will allow compositing using the rendered images. Set Frames to the resolution of your final image. Render the sequence.]
Change the Current Frame to 2. You should see a preview of your second render in the Viewer node. As of right now, there is only one image in the Image node. Change it to an Image Sequence and set the Offset to -1. This will allow compositing using the rendered images. Set Frames to the resolution of your final image. Render the sequence.

[image: OPTIONAL. Save the final .exr to whichever format you prefer using a File Output node.]
OPTIONAL. Save the final .exr to whichever format you prefer using a File Output node.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, it's simply the current limit because the underlying data type is `short`. You can retrieve the upper and lower limit for the property through

```
bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes["Time"].bl_rna.properties["frame_end"].hard_max
```

and

```
bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes["Time"].bl_rna.properties["frame_end"].hard_min
```

which are 32767 and -32768 respectively.

The reason for this is because Blender uses two variables `custom1` and `custom2` of type `short` declared in [`DNA_node_types.h`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/makesdna/DNA_node_types.h$253) for various node properties. This includes the start and end frame of the *Time* node as can be seen in [`static void def_time(StructRNA *srna)`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_nodetree.c$3950) from `rna_nodetree.c`.

Comment: So is there a way to bypass this by replacing the time node with a script (if so how) or am I SOL?

Comment: That depends on what your actual goal is. There may be otherways to accomplish it, without using the *Time* node. Writing a patch for a larger range would make sense though, since it should be able to cover the same range as the actual animation. Perhaps this could be discussed on devtalk or rightclickselect.

Comment: This basically https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ldLJ3e8jQw